# Alter datetime column to varchar with existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, varchar

I have table A and it has a column named `LastUpdateDate` in datetime format. It keeps date with time data like `Apr 18 2017 11:15AM`. I want to get rid of time data and keep date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

So I guess, I alter the the column to VARCHAR. But I have existing data. Do I get error when I alter the column? Or are there any other option? What should I do?

Comment: You need to alter it to `date` not `varchar`

Comment: SELECT convert(datetime, 'Apr 18 2017 11:15AM')

Comment: Why not keep the datetime and just select it as a date when you retrieve the data?

Comment: It means when I alter column to date, my existing data will not effect from the alter, right?

Comment: If you alter the column to date you will lose the time part. Do you not in fact want to alter the column in the table? Just in a SELECT result?

Comment: Ok, I am working for a company and I don't have a permission for SELECT, only able to INSERT. But alter to Date was worked, Thanks Martin !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** alter the column to a `varchar`.
If anything, you should alter it to a `date` data type:

```
 ALTER TABLE YourTable
 ALTER COLUMN LastUpdateDate DATE
 GO
```

Here is a sample table with some data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable 
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    LastUpdateDate datetime
)

INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES 
(GETDATE()),
(DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())),
(DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE())),
(DATEADD(DAY, 3, GETDATE())),
(DATEADD(DAY, 4, GETDATE()))
```

The alter table statement:

```
 ALTER TABLE YourTable
 ALTER COLUMN LastUpdateDate DATE
 GO
```

Test:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable
```

Result:

```
id  LastUpdateDate
1   18.04.2017 00:00:00
2   19.04.2017 00:00:00
3   20.04.2017 00:00:00
4   21.04.2017 00:00:00
5   22.04.2017 00:00:00
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/ZLPQM24785)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your select query convert the datetime column into short date

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,datetimecomlum) AS short_date FROM A
```